# i am getting following error when i am trying to run lambda function,error is indentation error at line no7

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

i am getting indentation error at line no.7 for s3 bucket saying syntax error,i am tryiing to run lambda function which basically copy s3 bucket data from source to destination when ever a new object is uploaded to s3 bucket based on sns topic and cloudwatch logs.

```
import urllib
import boto3
import ast
import json
print('Loading function')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sns_message = ast.literal_eval(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
target_bucket = context.function_name
source_bucket = str(sns_message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'])
key = str(urllib.unquote_plus(sns_message['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8'))
copy_source = {'Bucket':source_bucket, 'Key':key}
print ("Copying %s from bucket %s to bucket %s ..." % (key, source_bucket, target_bucket))
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::lambdadestd3s:role/lambdasource",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)
credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']
#use of temporary credentials for sts role
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken'],
)
s3.copy_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=key, CopySource=copy_source)
```

Comment: thats because 4 spaces are needed in 7th line

Comment: Please read how [Python Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not indent the next line after you define the function. It looks something like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        sns_message = ast.literal_eval(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
        target_bucket = context.function_name
```